# How to install LibreOffice on Scientific Linux 6.1?

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

How can I install (from a repository?*) a fresh but still stable version of LibreOffice under Scientific Linux 6.1 64bit?

* = this means I need updates too, so if there will be a newer stable version of LibreOffice, then I it should update it self (of course with the package manager set to auto update). Because if I just install a .rpm file then it wouldn't be updated if there are newer releases..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](http://unixbhaskar.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/how-to-manually-install-libreoffice-on-scientific-linux/) might help you:

1. Extract the RPMs:

   ```
   $ tar -xvzf LibO_3.5.2_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz
   ```
2. Install them all:

   ```
   $ cd LibO_3.5.2rc2_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US/RPMS
   $ sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm
   ```
3. Install the `freedesktop` RPM:

   ```
   $ cd desktop-integration
   $ sudo rpm -ivh libreoffice3.5-freedesktop-menus-3.5-202.noarch.rpm
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check if either of the following works:

```
yum groupinstall "Office/Productivity"
yum install libreoffice-base libreoffice-writer \
            libreoffice-calc libreoffice-impress
```