# How to install libreoffice in centos5 without yum?

Tags: centos, libreoffice

I'm trying to install the Libreoffice in CentOS 5.
Unfortunately, my system is separated with Internet. So I can't use the YUM for install.

Fortunately I found

https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.3.4.1/rpm/x86_64/

Could you guide me please where to start from here.
What file do I need to install and how to install in CentOS 5?

I just followed as https://vitux.com/how-to-install-libreoffice-on-centos-8/

But I got the error message the below after yum clean

```
# yum localinstall *.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining libobasis3.6-base-3.6.1.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis3.6-base-3.6.1.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis3.6-base-3.6.1.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
[worker@localhost RPMS]#
```

When I check /etc/yum.repos.d

```
[worker@localhost yum.repos.d]# ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1906 Jan  1  2018 CentOS-Base.repo
```

and CentOS-Base.repo looks like the below

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#
# http://vault.centos.org/?release=5&arch=i386&repo=os

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
```

#update

After **rpm -ivh *.rpm**
I've got this the below

```
[worker@localhost RPMS]# rpm -ivh *.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:libreoffice3.6-ure     ########################################### [  2%]
   2:libobasis3.6-core01    ########################################### [  4%]
   3:libobasis3.6-core02    ########################################### [  6%]
   4:libobasis3.6-core03    ########################################### [  7%]
   5:libobasis3.6-core04    ########################################### [  9%]
   6:libobasis3.6-core05    ########################################### [ 11%]
   7:libobasis3.6-core06    ########################################### [ 13%]
   8:libobasis3.6-core07    ########################################### [ 15%]
   9:libobasis3.6-en-US     ########################################### [ 17%]
  10:libobasis3.6-base      ########################################### [ 19%]
  11:libobasis3.6-impress   ########################################### [ 20%]
  12:libobasis3.6-en-US-base########################################### [ 22%]
  13:libobasis3.6-en-US-calc########################################### [ 24%]
  14:libobasis3.6-en-US-math########################################### [ 26%]
  15:libobasis3.6-en-US-res ########################################### [ 28%]
  16:libobasis3.6-en-US-writ########################################### [ 30%]
  17:libobasis3.6-calc      ########################################### [ 31%]
  18:libobasis3.6-draw      ########################################### [ 33%]
  19:libobasis3.6-images    ########################################### [ 35%]
  20:libreoffice3.6         ########################################### [ 37%]
  21:libobasis3.6-math      ########################################### [ 39%]
  22:libobasis3.6-writer    ########################################### [ 41%]
  23:libobasis3.6-binfilter ########################################### [ 43%]
  24:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 44%]
  25:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 46%]
  26:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 48%]
  27:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 50%]
  28:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 52%]
  29:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 54%]
  30:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 56%]
  31:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 57%]
  32:libobasis3.6-extension-########################################### [ 59%]
  33:libobasis3.6-gnome-inte########################################### [ 61%]
  34:libobasis3.6-graphicfil########################################### [ 63%]
  35:libobasis3.6-javafilter########################################### [ 65%]
  36:libobasis3.6-kde-integr########################################### [ 67%]
  37:libobasis3.6-ogltrans  ########################################### [ 69%]
  38:libobasis3.6-onlineupda########################################### [ 70%]
  39:libobasis3.6-ooofonts  ########################################### [ 72%]
  40:libobasis3.6-ooolinguis########################################### [ 74%]
  41:libobasis3.6-postgresql########################################### [ 76%]
  42:libobasis3.6-pyuno     ########################################### [ 78%]
  43:libobasis3.6-xsltfilter########################################### [ 80%]
  44:libreoffice3.6-base    ########################################### [ 81%]
  45:libreoffice3.6-calc    ########################################### [ 83%]
  46:libreoffice3.6-dict-en ########################################### [ 85%]
  47:libreoffice3.6-dict-es ########################################### [ 87%]
  48:libreoffice3.6-dict-fr ########################################### [ 89%]
  49:libreoffice3.6-draw    ########################################### [ 91%]
  50:libreoffice3.6-en-US   ########################################### [ 93%]
  51:libreoffice3.6-impress ########################################### [ 94%]
  52:libreoffice3.6-math    ########################################### [ 96%]
  53:libreoffice3.6-stdlibs ########################################### [ 98%]
  54:libreoffice3.6-writer  ########################################### [100%]
```

But nothing then after 100%. How do I launch the libreoffice? Do I need to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39312/165944

```
Extract the RPMs:

$ tar -xvzf LibO_3.5.2_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz
Install them all:

$ cd LibO_3.5.2rc2_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US/RPMS
$ sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm
Install the freedesktop RPM:

$ cd desktop-integration
$ sudo rpm -ivh libreoffice3.5-freedesktop-menus-3.5-202.noarch.rpm
```

https://unixbhaskar.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/how-to-manually-install-libreoffice-on-scientific-linux/

and resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -ivh xxx.rpm
```

but i bet can't install successful. Because maybe some dependency rpm need to install first.

Comment: I think rpm =ivh *.rpm work but where to launch the libreoffce?